# Compress Word (Docx) Files using Python

Tags: python, compression, docx

i am searching for a example, compressing images in a word file (~ 96ppi). I got serveral docx files, with different sizes. If i compress these word files with (Save as-> Options-> Compress Images), these files will loss there space ~80%.
The creator of these word files just copied some picutres into these files and didn't save the file for specific use (Just Save and good to go.).

So my question is, is it possible to compress these word files with python?